# Bootstrap 4 Not Obeying Height Directives

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, sass

I have 2 elements in my web layout that should take 25% and 75% of the visible screen height respectively using Bootstrap 4's `row` directives, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the height of the elements.

[image]

It looks like the email form and image view are simply the minimum height needed to wrap the element's contents. What am I doing wrong?

```
<template>
  <div class="container h-100" id="app">
    <div class="row h-25">
      <div class="image-container row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <img src="../assets/images/snaprefund_thin_stroke_cropped_opaque.png" alt="SnapRefund">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row h-75">
      <EmailForm/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<style>
.container {
  margin: 0;
  background: url(~@/assets/images/pic.jpg) repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 40%;
  max-width: 40%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `vh-100` instead of `h-100` in your `.container` and if that doesn't work, possibly try adding:

```
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
```

To your `.image-container` and see if it fixes it.

Comment: Using `vh-100` in container didn't change anything but modifying the css scripts as you mentioned did in fact work. Why is that? Seems like manipulating views via the script instead of the html is just better because it works more easily.

Comment: I prefer to use the scripts personally. But if you'd like to use the inline html, I believe an equivelent answer would be too add `vh-100 vw-100` to your `image-container` inline so it looks like this:  `<div class="image-container row justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100 vw-100">`